# Pesquisa de propriedades do TreeNode usando C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, treeview

Boa Tarde. Estou a tentar trabalhar com `TreeNode`s, gostaria de fazer uma pesquisa com base nas propriedades Texto do meu Nome, mas não estou a conseguir o resultado esperado.

O que eu queria que me aparecesse era só a parte que diz `Album1` (que é a minha propriedade texto). Deixo também abaixo o meu respectivo código. Não liguem para as condições no meu `if` pois era só mais uma tentativa de obter o pretendido. O que as condições fazem é apenas mostrar `Album1`, mas não os nodes que estejam lá dentro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
void FindRecursive2(TreeNode ^treeNode)
{
    System::Collections::IEnumerator^ myNodes = (safe_cast<System::Collections::IEnumerable^>(treeNode->Nodes))->GetEnumerator();
    while (myNodes->MoveNext())
    {
        // Responsável pela caixa de texto na imagem postada.
        System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult result = MessageBox::Show(this, myNodes->Current->ToString());

        if (treeNode->Text->ToString() == textBox4->Text || treeNode->Text->ToString() == textBox5->Text || treeNode->Text->ToString() == textBox6->Text)
            treeNode->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::ForestGreen;
        TreeNode^ v2 = safe_cast<TreeNode^>(myNodes->Current);
        FindRecursive2(v2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Não entendi direito o que você quer, mas acho que aquele `MessageBox::Show` deveria ou estar protegido por um `if`, ou estar fora do `while` ou só aparecer após um `return` ou coisa parecida.

Comment: A message box é so para eu testar o que é imprimido, eu queria so imprimir Album1. nao quero que apareça o "treeNode:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer assim:

```
void FindRecursive2(TreeNode ^treeNode)
{
    System::Collections::IEnumerator^ myNodes = (safe_cast<System::Collections::IEnumerable^>(treeNode->Nodes))->GetEnumerator();
    while (myNodes->MoveNext())
    {
        TreeNode^ v2 = safe_cast<TreeNode^>(myNodes->Current);

        // Responsável pela caixa de texto na imagem postada.
        System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult result = MessageBox::Show(this, v2->Text->ToString());

        // Talvez neste if você queira usar v2->Text ao invés de treeNode->Text.
        if (treeNode->Text->ToString() == textBox4->Text || treeNode->Text->ToString() == textBox5->Text || treeNode->Text->ToString() == textBox6->Text) {
            treeNode->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::ForestGreen;
        }

        FindRecursive2(v2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactamente, muito obrigado. fogo incrível  :)

Comment: @RADCP Ótimo. Fico feliz em ter te ajudado. :)